# How to post a form and string to MVC 4 controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Having problems sending multiple data over Post to MVC Controller
No matter what step I send by post it isn't received by the controller and defaults to 1, but it will still send the form correctly.

```
public class SetupP{
    public string fn {get;set;}
    etc...
}

public ActionResult Start(int step = 1, Setup SetupP = null){
    if(step == 1)
    if(step ==2)
}



$.post("/setup/Start", { step: 2, SetupP: $('#SetupForm').serialize() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#SetupForm').serialize()` returns a query string eg `single=Single&check=check1&radio=radio1` (from jQuery's [.seialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) example).

Therefore `{ step: 2, SetupP: $('#SetupForm').serialize() }` would attempt to present an entire query string as the single parameter `SetupP`.  It's a hybrid data format and won't work.

You can put the pieces together manually, like this :

```
$('#SetupForm').serialize() + '&step=2'
```

Or if the `step` value is available as a variable, then :

```
$('#SetupForm').serialize() + '&step=' + someVariable
```

Comment: Extremely helpful!